# Normed vector space $l^{2}$

Tags: metric-spaces

We have a normed vector space $l^{2}$ of Hilbert.

How can we show that

1) if **A** contained in $l^{2}$ is compact, then **A** is closed and bounded.

2) in $l^{2}$, there exists a closed and bounded subset that is not compact

Comment: Do you mean $\ell^2,$ the space of square-summable sequences?

Comment: Hilbert space (corrected)

Answer (score 1):

It is a basic theorem of Functional Analysis that the closed unit ball of any infinite dimensional normed vector space is not compact. Any book on Functional Analysis has a  proof. You can also show directly that $\{e_1,e_2,...\}$ is a closed and bounded set which has no convergent subsequence, hence not compact. Here $e_1=(1,0,0,\cdots ,0),e_2=(0,1,0,\cdots ),\cdots$.